# Intuition behind exact sequences as extensions in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, algebraic-groups, exact-sequence, abelian-categories

**Introduction:** There are certain categories of group schemes or group varieties in which one can define exact sequences. For instance, the categories of commutative group schemes of finite type over a field $k$ and of commutative affine group schemes over $k$ are abelian (see for instance [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38168/is-the-category-of-commutative-group-schemes-abelian)).
So let's say that we have a short exact sequence
$$ 0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$$
in such a suitable category (**bonus question:** examples of abelian categories of  group *varieties*?). There is, a priori, no reason why the sequence should be split. Yet people call such a $B$ (together with the maps) fitting in the above exact sequence an *extension of $C$ by $A$*. Note that this is true also for other categories and does not have to do with algebraic geometry specifically, but I am most interested in this setting.

**My question:** What kind of information can one deduce, in general, about $B$, knowing only $A$ and $C$? Does one know something about the underlying topological space of $B$ or of $B(k)$ up to homotopy, or even up to homeomorphism? Is it any better if we consider maps up to isogeny? Feel free to restrict to some specific category where there are better results.

I am asking this because the terminology seems to suggest, and it seems to me that people often assume, that $B$ is some kind of direct sum between $A$ and $C$, even though there is a priori no reason for this to be the case. The isomorphism theorem does imply that $B/A \cong C$, but this does not imply that we know how to obtain $B$ knowing $A$ and $C$, since there might be many possibilities for doing so.

**Approximate paraphrase 1:** A paraphrase of my question is: what do all possible $B$'s that fit in the above sequence have in common, topologically?

**Approximate paraphrase 2:** Is there some exact functor $F$ from some "geometric" category $\mathcal{I}$ to some "topological" category $\mathcal{J}$ such that in $\mathcal{J}$ exact sequences are always split or $F(B)$ is at least somehow isomorphic to $F(A) \oplus F(C)$ or something similar?

**Note:** I am aware of the fact that, at least for modules, the set of the $B$'s fitting in the above exact sequence, up to some equivalence and with some sum operation, is isomorphic to $Ext^1(C,A)$, but I think that the term *extension* gave rise to the notation $Ext$ rather than the converse, so this fact does not provide any useful insight.